# Linear search in R

Tags: r, search, linear-search

I am trying to write a simple code without using any function to find an element in an array in R. I want to apply linear search algorithm

```
arr= c(5,8,4,6,9,2)
x=9
i=1
for (i in 1:range(arr)){
  if (arr[i] == x) {
    print("found")
    break
  }else{
    i = i+1
  }
}
```

This is throwing me a warning sign. As I am new to R can anyone help me find the correct answer to this?

Comment: The `range` function returns a length 2 vector which is the range of the numeric values of the vector. I think you're looking for the `length` function which returns a length 1 integer vector indicating the length of the vector. Additionally, you do not need `i = i+1` because `for` already does that.

Comment: Why are you using `for` loop for this? You can do `arr == x`

Comment: @RonakShah Can you explain a bit. Can you give a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use :

```
arr= c(5,8,4,6,9,2)
x=9
if(any(arr == x)) 'Found' else 'Not Found'
#[1] "Found"
```

Without `if`/`else` :

```
c('Not found', 'Found')[any(arr == x) + 1]
```

Comment: If I also want to find the position of the element, how to do that?

Comment: That is `which(arr == x)`